# How do I properly refer to StorageFolders and StorageFiles in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c++-cx

I am trying to create a folder in my local directory, create a file in said folder, then write to the file.  However, due to my unfamiliarity with Visual C++, I am faced with two very similar errors I do not understand.  Here is what I have written:

```
    //Get local folder
    Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ sfolder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;

    String^ folderName = "Debugteststuff";
    String^ fileName = "test.txt";

    //Create new folder
    sfolder->CreateFolderAsync(folderName, Windows::Storage::CreationCollisionOption::FailIfExists);
    //Navigate to newly created directory
    sfolder = sfolder->GetFolderAsync(folderName);
    //Create new file inside directory
    sfolder->CreateFileAsync(fileName, Windows::Storage::CreationCollisionOption::FailIfExists);
    //Assign sfile to newly created file
    Windows::Storage::StorageFile^ sfile = sfolder->GetFileAsync(fileName);

    //Write to the file
    Windows::Storage::FileIO::WriteTextAsync(sfile,"this is written into the file");
```

However, with the following two lines of code:

```
    sfolder = sfolder->GetFolderAsync(folderName);
    Windows::Storage::StorageFile^ sfile = sfolder->GetFileAsync(fileName);
```

I get these errors:

> Error: a value of type
>   "Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation ^" cannot be assigned to an entity of type
>   "Windows::Storage::StorageFolder ^"
>
> Error: a value of type
>   "Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation
>   ^" cannot be assigned to an entity of type
>   "Windows::Storage::StorageFile ^"

Sorry if this is poorly formatted, I am new to the site.

Comment: That's a pretty basic skill you need to learn to have any hope of writing WinRT code in C++.  [You'll have to RTFM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187334.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am very new to Visual C++ as you probably gathered.  If this is happening because they are not structured as tasks, I will look into the link you provided.

Comment: Also check the [official samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess/cpp)